# Highlight cells on heatmap

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I'm actually using the `heatmap.2` package from `R`

and the idea is that I have a matrix as :

```
  COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
A    1    0    0    1
B    1    0    1    1
C    1    0    1    0
D    0    1    1    0
```

which gives me a heatmap such as :

```
heatmap.2(as.matrix(matrix), trace="none",density.info="none",key = F)
```

[image]

But now I would like to know if it is possible with `heatmap.2` from this matrix :

**matrix_hilight_coordonates**

```
 COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
A    A    B    B    B
B    A    A    A    A
C    A    A    A    B
D    B    B    B    B
```

with the same dimension to:

- highlight cells where there is a `B`  as in example A

OR

- hatch cells where there is a  `B`  as in example B

[image]

here is a related question : [Highlight Subset Cells From Heatmap By Row/Col Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890845/highlight-subset-cells-from-heatmap-by-row-col-index)

the problem is that they do not go from a specific df in order to highlight the cells.

Thank you very much for your time and help

data

**matrix1**

```
structure(list(COL1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), COL2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), COL3 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), COL4 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "1"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"))
```

**matrix_hilight_coordonates**

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), COL2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), COL3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), COL4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"))
```